# Implementing Observer Pattern with @Dependent

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, observer-pattern

As I am continuing working on my JSF project I have reached a point where I would need some help to get me further.

To start with, my entire project is available at this link: https://github.com/vasigorc/rimmaproject It compiles and runs.

In two words, I have a page for taking appointments. So far the only field for appointments is the date. It in entered via a primefaces calendar component. The backing **session** appointment bean implements an Observable interface (part of the Observer Design Pattern). Whenever the date value changes, an observer is notified. An observer is a **dependent** bean which calls a REST client to obtain an object representation of a weather forecast for the selected date. Once a date is selected and the end user clicks **submit** the weather forecast should appear in the right part of the same page.

**Testing done:** I have unit tested all part-taking methods, as well as the integration between the Observer and Observable implementations. But when I run the application, change the date and click 'Submit' the date doesn't appear.

I couldn't find a stackoverflow ticket which would describe the same problem, but I found an IBM article which describes how to implement different Design Patterns in JSF. Their advice is to use the event listener approach. Before I take this U-turn in the design of my application I would like to get your advice in an attempt to find a flaw in the way my application is built now.

**The code** 
**Front end**
Page for taking appointments:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
        <h:form>     
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <span>#{copy.pickadate}</span>
                <p:calendar id="calendar" value="#{appointmentFormBean.selectedDate}" locale="fr"
                            mindate="today" maxdate="today+90" mode="popup"
                            pattern="yyyy-MM-dd">                
                </p:calendar>
                <input id="requestButton" type="button" value="#{copy.submitButton}">
                    <f:ajax event="click" execute="calendar" render="out weatherwidget"></f:ajax>
                </input>                
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>    
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <ui:include id="weatherwidget" src="restservice/weatherWidget.xhtml"/>
    </div>
    <div><h:outputText id="out" value="#{appointmentFormBean.selectedDate}"></h:outputText></div>
```

**'The weather widget'**:

```
 <ui:composition>        
        <h:panelGrid columns="3" class="table table-bordered">
            <h:outputText rendered="#{appointmentFormBean.datePickerActivated}">#{forecastBeanTwo.forecast.day}</h:outputText>
        </h:panelGrid>            
</ui:composition>
```

**Appointment backing bean's signature:**

```
@Named(value = "appointmentFormBean")
@SessionScoped
public class AppointmentFormBean implements Serializable, Observed
```

the methods responsible for calling the Observer

```
public void setSelectedDate(Date selectedDate) {
    this.selectedDate = selectedDate;
    notifyVGObservers();
    setDatePickerActivated(true);
}
@Override
public void notifyVGObservers() {
    observers.stream().map((observer1) -> (VGObserver) observer1).forEach((observer) -> {
        observer.update(selectedDate);
    });
}
```

**The 'Observer' Bean's signature and Managed Property declaration:**

```
@ManagedBean
@Dependent
public class WeatherForecastBean implements Serializable, VGObserver
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{appointmentFormBean}")
private AppointmentFormBean formBean;
```

**Point of the injection of the observable..**

```
//point of IoC
public void setFormBean(AppointmentFormBean formBean) {
    this.formBean = formBean;
    formBean.registerVGObserver(this);
}
```

**Finally, the update method:**

```
Override
public void update(Date selectedDate) {
    /*
        get the 15 days from today date object
        and check whether the client requested day is not 
        after it.
    */
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, +15); 
    if (selectedDate.after(cal.getTime())) {
        /*
            So, if the selected date is after today+15 days
            then we will tell the client that we cannot grab a weathe for him
            i.e. DailyForecast = UnavailableForecast.class
        */
        setForecast(new UnavailableForecast());
    }else{
        /*
            Now that we know that the selected date is within the range
            of available forecasts, we need to extract the requested day 
            forecast (represented by a Time object) 
            from the total of 16 available days
        */
        java.sql.Date sqlDate = utilToSql(selectedDate);   
        Time requestedTime = findGoodTime(dwr.getDays(), 
                (Time t)->sqlDate.toString().equals(t.getDay()));
        setForecast(new TimeAdapter(requestedTime));
    }        
}
```

It is not an easy question. As I said, the full code is available at github, but you're also welcome to ask any questions. Any advice would help a lot.

Comment: In HTTP, user has to send a request in order to get a response.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am trying to send a partial (asynchronous) request when a user clicks the button with the id "requestButton".

Answer (score 0):

I am giving up on my old design as I need to move forward with the project. I abandoned the Observer-Observable object relation, and am taking the path suggested by the mentioned before IBM article:

> Observer pattern
>   The intent of the Observer pattern is to notify all dependent objects (or observers) automatically when the state in the subject changes. The JSF framework implements the Observer pattern in UI components. JSF technology has two kinds of built-in events: ActionEvent and ValueChangedEvent. ActionEvent is useful in determining the activation of user interface components such as buttons. When a user clicks on the button, the JSF implementation notifies one or more action listeners added to the button. The button is activated or the state of the button (subject) changes. All listeners (or observers) are notified of the changes of state in subject that are added to the button. Similarly, when the value in the input UI component changes, the JSF implementation notifies ValueChangeListeners.

Source: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-dsgnpatjsf/

These are the changes that I have made.

**In the front-end** I have added a PrimeFaces *eventListener*:

```
<p:calendar id="calendar" value="#{appointmentFormBean.selectedDate}" locale="fr"
                            mindate="today" maxdate="today+90" mode="popup"
                            pattern="yyyy-MM-dd">    
                    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{forecastBeanTwo.handleDateSelect}"/>
                </p:calendar>
```

In the back-end I have changed the update() method with the handleDateSelect() method:

```
public void handleDateSelect(SelectEvent event){
    /*
        get the 15 days from today date object
        and check whether the client requested day is not 
        after it.
    */
    Date selectedDate= (Date)event.getObject();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, +15); 
    if (selectedDate.after(cal.getTime())) {
        /*
            So, if the selected date is after today+15 days
            then we will tell the client that we cannot grab a weathe for him
            i.e. DailyForecast = UnavailableForecast.class
        */
        setForecast(new UnavailableForecast());
    }else{
        /*
            Now that we know that the selected date is within the range
            of available forecasts, we need to extract the requested day 
            forecast (represented by a Time object) 
            from the total of 16 available days
        */
        java.sql.Date sqlDate = utilToSql(selectedDate);   
        Time requestedTime = findGoodTime(dwr.getDays(), 
                (Time t)->sqlDate.toString().equals(t.getDay()));
        setForecast(new TimeAdapter(requestedTime));
    }  
    setBeanActivated(true);
}
```

And everything works ..to my dismay though, because this design looks like a work-around.